# phylotools::sub.taxa.label() error when substituting tree tip label

Tags: r, tree, phylogeny, ape-phylo

Please use the File Dropper link for the R project file with data and codes:

> https://filedropper.com/d/s/O4IkyFWpP54Ttb0yjODMlaUjhITOXR

OR

> https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_AHbjNrgeyiGMhbh-StlqakjXmcSDHnM?usp=sharing

I have a phylogeny tree of the Eucalypt Clade (tree1) from Thornhill et al 2019

I have deleted some outgroup *spp.* and *sp.* synonyms :

```
#Deleting outgroups and synonyms
ToBEDeleted <- ToBEDeleted %>%
  str_replace(" ","_")

tree1.Deleted <- ape::drop.tip(tree1,ToBEDeleted)

tree1.Deleted$tip.label %>%
  length()

length(tree1$tip.label)
```

After that I tried to replace 5 tree tips using a df with their updated names

```
> renamed
                     tips                       abr
1 Eucalyptus_largiflorens        Eucalyptus_bicolor
2 Eucalyptus_pilligaensis     Eucalyptus_woollsiana
3    Eucalyptus_clelandii   Eucalyptus_clelandiorum
4  Eucalyptus_brachycorys Eucalyptus_comitae-vallis
5    Eucalyptus_trivalvis       Eucalyptus_trivalva

#Replacing synonyms

phylotools::sub.taxa.label(tree1.Deleted, renamed)
```

But I ran into this error:

```
> phylotools::sub.taxa.label(tree1.Deleted, renamed)
5 Names Eucalyptus_largiflorens Eucalyptus_pilligaensis Eucalyptus_clelandii Eucalyptus_brachycorys Eucalyptus_trivalvis in reference table

            can not be found in the tree.

Phylogenetic tree with 624 tips and 686 internal nodes.

Tip labels:
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, ...

Rooted; includes branch lengths.
Warning message:
In phylotools::sub.taxa.label(tree1.Deleted, renamed) :
  The number of tip labels in phylogenetic

                 tree differ from the reference table.
```

While the above error states that the tree tips are absent from the tree, a quick check below shows that the target tip names in the reference table matches 5 tip names int the tree.

```
tree1.Deleted$tip.label %>% 
  stringr::str_detect(paste(renamed$tips,collapse = "|")) %>%
  summary()

> tree1.Deleted$tip.label %>% 
+   stringr::str_detect(paste(renamed$tips,collapse = "|")) %>%
+   summary()
   Mode   FALSE    TRUE 
logical     682       5
```

Any advice on how to troubleshoot?

Many thanks

Hong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's my mistake, the reference table argument should have the same number of rows as the total number of tree tips.